# I would like to protect a technique I use to teach meditation

Tags: method, protection, teaching

I have a method I use for teaching meditation that I would like to patent, or at least protect. Suggestions?

Comment: Does it involve a machine, maybe a flickering light?

Comment: I think we need more information. As George White indicates, the answer depends on whether this is a verbal technique or if there is a device or perhaps software involved.

Comment: Perhaps revenant? https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/40539/how-can-one-protect-a-teaching-method